# How do you get an ActivityResultRegistry reference from an Activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get this example code to work in Java:

> https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result
>
> ```
> private final ActivityResultLauncher<Void> mTakePicture =
>         registerForActivityResult(new TakePicturePreview(), mRegistry, new ActivityResultCallback<Bitmap>() {
>             @Override
>             public void onActivityResult(Bitmap thumbnail) {
>                 mThumbnailLiveData.setValue(thumbnail);
>             }
>     });
> ```

The example happens to be a "Fragment", and it gets mRegistry from the constructor:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private final ActivityResultRegistry mRegistry;
    ...
    public MyFragment(@NonNull ActivityResultRegistry registry) {
        super();
        mRegistry = registry;
    }
```

My test case is an Activity (the "MainActivity"), not a Fragment:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    private  ActivityResultRegistry activityResultRegistry;
```

Q: How can I initialize my registry ("activityResultRegistry") in this scenario?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was easier than I thought:

```
private ActivityResultRegistry activityResultRegistry = this.getActivityResultRegistry();
```

Comment: .....................